# Wordpress PHP Form - Data being deleted when leaving page

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am hoping someone out there could help with my particular issue.

I am currently working on a question/answer form which displays on a custom post type called 'lp_lesson' within Wordpress.

I have successfully created the question form which resides on the admin side of Wordpress. You can generate multiple question fields and it dynamically saved to the SQL database. 
The questions are saved as an array in post_meta.

On the front end of the website, for that particular custom post type, it will display the question fields and beneath each question field will have a textarea field for the user to input their answer to that particular question.
The answers are saved as an array in user_meta.

All forms and successfully submitting to the database.

BUT

After submitting the form and leaving the page, once you return, it will delete all the data that was once submitted there.

I suspected that it might be because I had update_user_meta before the form, it might be submitting blank form data, but I had tried placing update_user_meta after the form and it doesn't make a difference.

Please see my function below.

```
function activity_form_function() {
    global $current_user;

    $course         = LP()->global['course'];
    $item       = LP()->global['course-item'];
    $courseID   = $course->ID;
    $itemID     = $item->ID;

    $lp_lesson_activity = get_post_meta( $item->ID, 'activities', true );

    if ( !empty( $lp_lesson_activity[0] ) ) {

         ?>

        <div class="lp-lesson-activity">
            <h4>Activity</h4>
            <form name="lessonactivity" action="" method="POST">
                <ul>
                    <?php
                    $c = 0;
                    foreach ($lp_lesson_activity as $activity) {
                    $activity_question_push = "AID" . $courseID . $itemID . $c++;
                    $assessment = $activity['assessment'];

                    $fieldname = 'activities_' . $itemID;
                    $activity_question_answer = $_POST['activities'];
                    update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, $fieldname, $activity_question_answer);
                    $activity_question_answerGUD = get_user_meta( $current_user->ID, $fieldname, true);
                    ?>
                        <li class="lp-activity-question">
                            <span><?php echo $activity['title']; ?></span>
                            <div class="lp-activity-answer-container">
                                <input type="hidden" name="activities[<?php echo $activity_question_push; ?>][question]" value="">
                                <textarea placeholder="Enter answer here" name="activities[<?php echo $activity_question_push; ?>][answer]"><?php echo $activity_question_answerGUD[$activity_question_push]['answer']; ?></textarea>
                                <?php if ( $assessment ) { ?>
                                    <span class="notice">This activity will be assessed and will contribute to your final grade. Please take your time.</span>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    <?php }

}
```

Comment: Update: It is something to do with update_user_meta. I have found out that if I remove update_user_meta completely, it will stop the issue from occurring which means I am free to click away from the page and return to the page and the data will still be there in the database. But removing update_user_meta means that the fields wont update. So I am back to square one.

Comment: I have also moved the entirety of my function to a normal post type, and the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

First check that user_post_meta is deleted or not using below function in functions.php

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_show_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_show_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { 
global $current_user;

    $course         = LP()->global['course'];
    $item       = LP()->global['course-item'];
    $courseID   = $course->ID;
    $itemID     = $item->ID;

    $lp_lesson_activity = get_post_meta( $item->ID, 'activities', true );
$fieldname = 'activities_' . $itemID; ?>
<h3>Extra profile information</h3>

<table class="form-table">

    <tr>
        <th><label for="twitter">activities No</label></th>

        <td>
            <input type="text" name="activities-no" id="activities-no" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_user_meta( $current_user->ID,'$fieldname',true ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            <span class="description">Please enter your activities No.</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<?php }

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function my_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
    return false;


update_user_meta( $current_user->ID, '$fieldname', sanitize_text_field($_POST['activities-no']) );
}
```

It will show activities in user -> profile in wp admin panel

if it shows that update does not deleting

Comment: Please first check it.if it there means i can give some answers.